# MVC RAZOR assign javascript variable to C# variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to assign javascript variable to c# variable in mvc razor view?
e.g.

```
<script>@cSharpVar=javascriptVar;</script>
```

Also, is it possible to pass javascript variable to c# method?
e.g.

```
@{var test=Utility.MethodName(javascriptVar,cSharpVar)}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**.

C# runs on the server; Javascript runs on the client.
It does not make sense to have them interact.

You should use AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

The short and long answer is: **NO**.

All these scenarios should be covered by AJAX calls to the server